# What is causing the route to change (ikely because form is submitting), i also added return false in the function?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, web

I am currently building a single page web app and wanted that js handle the form submission and so that route remain the same. But when i click the submit button route changes,

JS Code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  // Use buttons to toggle between views
  document.querySelector('#inbox').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('inbox'));
  document.querySelector('#sent').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('sent'));
  document.querySelector('#archived').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('archive'));
  document.querySelector('#compose').addEventListener('click', compose_email);
  // By default, load the inbox
  load_mailbox('inbox');
});

function compose_email() {

  // Show compose view and hide other views
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'block';

  // Clear out composition fields
  document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value = '';
  document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value = '';
  document.querySelector('#compose-body').value = '';
}

function load_mailbox(mailbox) {
  
  // Show the mailbox and hide other views
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'none';

  // Show the mailbox name
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').innerHTML = `<h3>${mailbox.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + mailbox.slice(1)}</h3>`;

}

function send_mail(event){
  const recipients = document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value;
  const subject = document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value;
  const body = document.querySelector('#compose-body').value;

  //send the email as post to the server 
  fetch('/emails', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      recipients: recipients,
      subject: subject,
      body: body
    })
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      //loading the sent box after sending the email
      load_mailbox('sent');
    })

  return false;
}

document.querySelector('#compose-form').onsubmit = send_mail;
```

HTML code:

```
{% extends "mail/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block body %}
    <h2>{{ request.user.email }}</h2>

    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="inbox">Inbox</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="compose">Compose</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="sent">Sent</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="archived">Archived</button>
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>
    <hr>

    <div id="emails-view">
    </div>

    <div id="compose-view">
        <h3>New Email</h3>
        <form id="compose-form">

            <div class="form-group">
                From: <input disabled class="form-control" value="{{ request.user.email }}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                To: <input id="compose-recipients" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="compose-subject" placeholder="Subject">
            </div>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="compose-body" placeholder="Body"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
    <script src="{% static 'mail/inbox.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

What i tried is putting the last line of code, in the event listener of DOMContentLoaded and this works fine. what is causing this problem why route is changing ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `event.preventDefault()` at the start of the function call send_mail() like this

```
function send_mail(event){
event.preventDefault(); // this will prevent the navigation.
const recipients = document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value;
}
```